# How to get slices of different dimensions from tensorflow tensor.

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a 3D tensor `x` that is of type float, and a 1D tensor `y` that is of type int. I want to get the average of each slice of the second axis of `x` from 0 to the index corresponding to each element of `y`. In other words, if `x` and `y` were numpy arrays, I would want

```
In [1]: y = [1, 2, 1, 1]

In [2]: x = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]])

In [3]: np.array([np.mean(x[index, :item], axis=0) for index, item in enumerate(y)])
Out[22]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  2.]])
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case, you could use a `tf.while_loop`:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

y = tf.constant([1, 2, 1, 1])
x = tf.constant([[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],
                 [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],
                 [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]],
                 [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]], dtype=np.float32)

y_len = tf.shape(y)[0]
idx = tf.zeros((), dtype=tf.int32)
res = tf.zeros((0,2))
_, res = tf.while_loop(
    lambda idx, res: idx < y_len,
    lambda idx, res: (idx + 1, tf.concat([res, tf.reduce_mean(x[idx, :y[idx]], axis=0)[tf.newaxis]], axis=0)),
    [idx, res],
    shape_invariants=[idx.get_shape(), tf.TensorShape([None, 2])])

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
res.eval()

# returns
# array([[ 1.,  2.],
#        [ 2.,  3.],
#        [ 1.,  2.],
#        [ 1.,  2.]], dtype=float32)
```

In the less general case where the length of `y` is known at graph construction time, you could spare yourself the use of a `tf.while_loop` and loop in python (could result in a large graph if `y` has many elements).

```
y_len = y.shape.num_elements()
res = tf.Variable(np.zeros((y_len, 2), dtype=np.float32))
res = tf.tuple([res] + [res[idx].assign(tf.reduce_mean(x[idx, :y[idx]], axis=0))
   for idx in range(y_len)])[0]
```

Note that you could also simply cascade the updates, not unlike the general case with `tf.while_loop`:

```
y_len = y.shape.num_elements()
res = tf.zeros((0,2))
for idx in range(y_len):
  res = tf.concat([res, tf.reduce_mean(x[idx, :y[idx]], axis=0)[tf.newaxis]], axis=0)
```

but now the updates need to happen sequentially. In the former solution, updates for each row happen are independent and can run in parallel, which I think is better.

Comment: Thanks! Your second block of code is giving me a FailedPreconditionError though.

Comment: I ran it in the wrong place, oops, now the problem is fixed. Thanks.